# Activating path selection automatically in PS

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pen-tool

Is there some way to make Photoshop to activate the selection automatically when the path is closed?
In GIMP I would make a closed path, hit enter and the selection would immediately be activated with "marching ants".
It's not the case in PS - I tried hitting enter and tried to select "Make selection" option after right clicking on the path - still, the path remains inactive.
Surely it must be something wrong with my PS settings somewhere because I find it hard to believe that PS devs would make such a trivial task so unintuitive.

EDIT: OK, after some additional random clicking I found that I can make the selection active ONLY by clicking "Make: Selection..." in the upper left corner. Is it the only way PS allows to activate selection? LOL

[image]

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you want to use the Pen tool and not the Lasso Selection tool..?

Comment: Command/Ctrl click the path thumbnail in the Path Panel.

Comment: There is a difference between activating a path and selecting it. Simply the path isnt selected just activated you still need to select it if you want to use the rmb method. See just going to a drawer does not activate your sports pants. See there can be many subpaths in the single path. Admittedly this is bad design but it is a inevitable outcome of years and years of scope creep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if I understood your problem entirely, but there's a shortcut I found on Adobe [community](https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop-ecosystem/pen-tool-selection-keyboard-shortcut/td-p/3333539).

[image]

You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> in Windows. It will make selection. But you won't get option to enter amount of feather. You can use `Select > Modify` options though.

[image]

You can edit shortcut in Keyboard shortcuts.